# how can i use pagination in recyclerview when data comes from youtube API.

Tags: android

I am unable to get an idea how can I use pagination when I reached the last item(if 20 items per page) All data comes from youtube server using Youtube API. I use pagination and hit server to get next 20 item data.I use recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code snippet in your app.

```
private boolean loading = true;
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
    {
        if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) 
            {
                if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) 
                {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                    //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: when i scroll at last nothing happens and no Log.v shows message in logcat

Comment: thanx bro it works....i did mistake ...i use mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()); two time one in on create other when seting the adapter